# Speakers not working on ASUS Zenbook 14 OLED UX3402ZA-KM023W

Tags: sound, asus, speakers

I recently bought the ASUS Zenbook 14 OLED UX3402ZA-KM023W with intel core i7-1260p and the speakers don't work on ubuntu.
I'm using dualboot between windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04LTS (kernel -> Ubuntu 5.15.0-58.64-generic 5.15.74).
Anyone knows how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Please check solution (SSDT patch) described here: https://gist.github.com/lamperez/862763881c0e1c812392b5574727f6ff?permalink_comment_id=4531290#gistcomment-4531290

6.x (6.3.7) kernel required to work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. If you provide an answer, please put the solution to the question in the answer. Simply linking to the solution means that if that link breaks or is modified, your answer then isn't useful.